# regex in preg_match to NOT match line comment source code and capture wrong subpattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, capture, negative-lookbehind

*[NOTE: I rewrite my post for better describing my question with my thanks to mario and I'L'I answered previously]*

I want to match these patterns (**and also allow a number of whitespaces in-between**):

```
Connection variable = new DBConnection
variable = new DBConnection
```

but NOT match:

```
//Connection variable = new DBConnection
//variable = new DBConnection
//    Connection variable = new DBConnection
//    variable = new DBConnection
```

and lastly capture the variable name.

This is my regexp

```
#(?<!//)(?:\s*Connection\s+)+(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection#
```

but the last two lines in not-match example list still match. How can I fix my regex? Is it because negative lookbehind must check things **immediately before** some **fixed-length string** only?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what it should match?

Comment: You made the match on `(Connection)?` optional.

Comment: @I'L'i : I've modified my post to reply to your questions

Comment: @mario: I did it on purpose. Pls. see my reply to I'L'l in my post

Comment: The `(.+)` is going to match **whatever** precedes the equal sign.

Comment: Your regex does not match `variable = new DBConnection` because you require `Connection\s+` to be before a required `\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection`, what is the rule to match it? Sorry, but matching something not preceded with something of unknown length in PHP regex is solved with a bit of common programming logic that depends on whether you are extracting or replacing. What are you doing? (Also, that requires a pattern that matches what you need, and your regex does not seem to work).

Comment: @wiktor: the trailing + in (?:\s*Connection\s+)+ means optional

Comment: You may make anything optional using `?` or `*` quantifiers, not `+`. Probably you want [`^(\s*//)?(?:\s*Connection\s+)?(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection`](https://regex101.com/r/QU9SLs/1) and fail al matches where Group 1 is not empty. Try it like [this code on your side](https://ideone.com/XvqxWv).

Comment: @Wiktor: OMG! You are right. Maybe it's the problem. I'll try it.

Comment: @Wiktor: You regex is smart. I never come up with the-other-way idea. Please put it as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks! (Though I still don't know how to use negative lookbehind)

Comment: @Wiktor: There's a problem. My program always read in an entire source program file into a string and do preg_match. I remove the begin line ^ from regex. It seems works fine now.

Comment: Ok, let me post an answer with explanations since now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of the two approaches.

## Approach 1: [SKIP-FAIL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

You may match all lines that start with `//` and skip them, and only match your substrings in other contexts.

```
'~^(\s*//.*)(*SKIP)(*F)|^(?:\s*Connection\s+)?(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QU9SLs/3)

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Q9hplf):

```
$re = '~^(\s*//.*)(*SKIP)(*F)|^(?:\s*Connection\s+)?(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection~m';
$str = "Connection variable = new DBConnection\n    variable = new DBConnection\n    //\n    //Connection variable = new DBConnection\n    //variable = new DBConnection\n    //    Connection variable = new DBConnection\n    //    variable = new DBConnection";
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Connection variable = new DBConnection
    [1] =>     variable = new DBConnection
)
```

## Approach 2: Optional capturing group and a bit of post-processing

In PHP PCRE regex patterns, you cannot use infinite-width lookbehinds meaning the patterns inside cannot be quantified with `*`, `+`, `*?`, `+?`, `?`, `?`, `{1,4}`, `{3,}` quantifiers. Moreover, you cannot use nested alternation either.

A usual workaround is to use an **optional capturing group** and check its value after a match is found. If the group value is not empty, it means the match should be "failed", discarded, else, grab the capture you need.

Here is an example regex:

```
'~^(\s*//)?(?:\s*Connection\s+)?(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QU9SLs/2):

[image]

The green highlighted substrings are Group 1 matches. We can check them in the code like this:

```
$result = "";                    // Result is empty
if (preg_match($rx, $s, $m)) {   // Is there a match?
    if (empty($m[1])) {          // Is the match group #1 empty?
        $result = $m[0];         // If yes, we found a result
    }
}                                // Else, result will stay empty
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/XvqxWv):

```
$strs = ['Connection variable = new DBConnection', 'variable = new DBConnection', '//Connection variable = new DBConnection', '//variable = new DBConnection'];
$rx = '~^(\s*//)?(?:\s*Connection\s+)?(.+?)\s*=\s*new\s+DBConnection~m';
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    echo "$s:\n";
    if (preg_match($rx, $s, $m)) {
        if (empty($m[1])) {
            echo "FOUND:" . $m[0] . "\n--------------\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "NOT FOUND\n--------------\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Connection variable = new DBConnection:
FOUND:Connection variable = new DBConnection
--------------
variable = new DBConnection:
FOUND:variable = new DBConnection
--------------
//Connection variable = new DBConnection:
//variable = new DBConnection:
```

Same technique can be used with `preg_replace_callback` if you need to replace.

Comment: Though my original intention is to use negative lookbehind to exclude line comment statements but I can't get it right. However, an answer that can solve problem is a good answer. Thanks for Wiktor giving me a different-idea answer.

Comment: @ScottChu Ok, on second thought, you can do something different. I will update with another soluition.